# ggplot: graphic issue with multiple graphs in a column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to set a few graphs in one column. The graph output, also the html knit output, does not extend the view frame of all graphs. In this way, the height of each additionally added graph decreases.

[image: Smashed graph view picture]

Corresponding code:

```
p_load(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = displ, y = hwy))

p2 <- ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_bar(aes(x = as.character(year), fill = drv), position = "dodge") + 
  labs(x = "year")

p3 <- ggplot(mpg) + 
  geom_density(aes(x = hwy, fill = drv), colour = NA) + 
  facet_grid(rows = vars(drv))

p4 <- ggplot(mpg) + 
  stat_summary(aes(x = drv, y = hwy, fill = drv), geom = "col", fun.data = mean_se) +
  stat_summary(aes(x = drv, y = hwy), geom = "errorbar", fun.data = mean_se, width = 0.5)

p5 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(x = displ, y = hwy)) + 
  geom_point()

p6 <-ggplot(mpg, aes(displ, hwy, colour = class)) + 
  geom_point()

p1/ p2 / p3 / p4 / p5 / p6
```

I used [Ggplot Arrange Plots Manual](https://ggplot2-book.org/arranging-plots.html)

How I can extend the complete view frame height for each added graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about html knit output from a .Rmd document, the way to increase the display panel for the plot is to edit the parameter of the block of r code. For example:

````
> ```{r, fig.height=10, fig.width=6}
> p1/ p2 / p3 / p4 / p5 / p6
> ```
````